# xamarin android binding enum with more than data property

Tags: xamarin, enums, binding, aar

I have a java library that I want to bind to in Xamarin. The library contains an enum with more than one property, defined below:

```
public enum WriteType {
  WITH_RESPONSE(WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT, PROPERTY_WRITE),
  WITHOUT_RESPONSE(WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE, PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE),
  SIGNED(WRITE_TYPE_SIGNED, PROPERTY_SIGNED_WRITE);

  public final int writeType;
  public final int property;

  WriteType(final int writeType, final int property) {
    this.writeType = writeType;
    this.property = property;
  }
}
```

When compiling, Visual studio generates the enum as class, but the WriteByte constructor has "int" return type (i.e. treated as a function). It generates an error:

**"CS0542 'WriteType': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"**

How to properly bind to enum with more than one property?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that visual studio changes the first character of member names to capital on binding. This aparently conflicts with the enum name itself.

I changed the member name and now binds successfully (no error).